# Do rubber bike pedals or rubber pedal covers exist?

Tags: pedals

I'm in a position where bringing my bike into the apartment is my best option at the moment.  However, it is possible for metal edges of the bike pedals to catch the wooden edges of doorways.

To prevent damage, I'm looking for some sort of rubber bumper to put on the bike pedals, or else find bike pedals with rubberised outer surfaces to avoid damaging things they bump into.

Has anyone found such pedals or bumpers?

Comment: Old bicycle inner tubes work well. Just slide it over the pedal.

Comment: or glue it to platform pedals

Comment: How about just a pair of socks or a heavy cloth bag.

Answer (score 7):

A short length of foam pipe insulation should do the job.  It's cheap, will fit into your pocket, and you can get it at any hardware store or plumbing supply shop.  You could also slide it onto your top, down, or seat tube for storage.

It looks like this:

[image]

Choose the size based on the type of pedals you use.  Platform pedals will require a larger diameter and clipless pedals a smaller diameter.  You want it big enough so you can easily slide it over the pedal but small enough that it stays put.

Comment: So add/remove the foam when entering/exiting buildings and keep it with you otherwise. I have platform pedals and I fear an inconveniently wide diameter of foam to stash. Would help if it was pedal-shaped, but maybe I can shape it.

Comment: @Graham - For storage, just slide it right onto your top tube, seat tube, or down tube and that way it'll always be handy and not consuming a pocket.

Answer (score 7):

A lot of platform pedals are made of plastics which won't scratch things, like [this one.](http://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=42731&category=114) They're pretty much available everywhere for about 10 dollars, though a clear one will pretty much just transfer dirt if it hits. You can also put some duct tape or electrical tape or something over the edges of the pedal (this should essentially be free). Note that certain tapes may leave some residue if they do rub. There are also slightly odd platform pedals which seem to be promising like the [Ergon PC2](http://www.ergon-bike.com/us/en/product/pc2), though I haven't used one .

Another option is folding pedals, such as [this one, by Sunlite](http://sunlitecycling.com/product_detail.php?short_code=Folding&cl1=PEDALS) (these are the cheapest ones available AFAIK, at around 20 dollars). Typically, you push/pull some tabs, pull the pedal out a bit and can fold the pedal up. These are often used for folding bicycles, and should essentially eliminate the problem (provided you buy a quality folding pedal, as if somethings going to go on the pedal, it will be the folding mechanism).

Yet another option is to use a small clipless pedal, such as the [Crank Brothers Eggbeaters](http://www.crankbrothers.com/pedals_eggbeater.php) (the cheapest clipless pedals are around 50 dollars). They're small but you'll need to get special shoes - some SPD shoes (probably another 75 dollars or so) are okay for walking in. Other pedals have a bit of platform, which you may or may not like, such as the [Crank Brothers Candy](http://www.crankbrothers.com/pedals_candy3.php). Of course, if the platform is too big, it doesn't really cure the problem.

Comment: So far I've taken your advice to add duct tape around the edges of my existing pedals.  I've seen plastic pedals similar in shape to the ones you linked, but for €30 in bright orange.  I'm not going clipless, I cycle casually to into town.

Comment: Not sure which ones you're talking about, but 30 euros for your basic platform pedals is highway robbery. 30 euros for folders isn't bad though. You can also take some foam tape, put them on top of the duct tape and then cover that with foam tape for waterproofing.

Answer (score 0):

In short. Yes they do. Finding them may be hard.

See the end of [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/15817/3140)

Comment: Ok, I see the mention of composite pedals with rubberized tops.  I've found MKS 3000R Full Rubber Commuter Pedals which have rubber blocks but metal at the outside. I had hoped for rubber on all edges.  But they may help.

Comment: Hey, it seems BBB Cycling (http://bbbcycling.com/bike-parts/pedals/) makes pedals with alumuminium alloy inside, composite outside.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a few coats of [plasti-dip](http://www.plastidip.com/) on metal pedals.  If you degrease the metal properly before you apply it it sticks really well and provides a grippy rubbery plastic surface, much thicker than paint.  I've used it to stop metal clamps scratching campervan bodywork and improve grip.

It might even work on hard plastic pedals (which are harder than typical household paint or plaster).

Comment: I was thinking of some sort of liquid rubber. Plasti-Dip looks like just the thing.  It seems like Plasti-Dip would be quite thin (relative to dipping the pedal in rubber), but that may be enough to avoid scratching or chipping.  Only downside is it looks to be about €20 a can.

Comment: @Graham, it's quite pricy but you can actually brush it on meaning you only need the little can to do quite a lot.  There are also vinyl dips, but they don't grip as well (or stick as well to the metal) so you wouldn't vinyl under your shoes.  I'm also not sure about applying these at home.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer of my own (but not accepting it), which is the method I'm using as a stop-gap measure in addition to Batman's duct tape.

I have cut out cardboard and glued and taped it into a rectangular shape just wide and high enough to slide over the pedal, with a 1 centimetre overhang.

A cardboard rectangular tube folds flat for stashing, similar to how Carey Gregory's foam tube can be stashed on the frame.   However, cardboard will not survive heavy rain.

Still, cardboard is readily available to me and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called “Pedal Sock.” It will help to prevent / reduce the damages that your bicycle pedals can cause, when transporting or storing you bike. I have even seen people use then when riding their bikes.  The material that it is made of is flexible with some shock absorbing properties. They seem simply to use and can withstand a good deal of punishment; which make them durable. For the purpose they serve and there durability, they are not expensive. I first found them surfing the internet (pedalsock.com), since then I have seen them in use.

Comment: For that matter, a plain old sock would probably work quite well, installed just before needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can mail order good ol' fashioned rubber pedals:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0012TIUTG/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_2?pf_rd_p=1535523722&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B000V2RQ7W&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1SQX7R97MRKKDCE8Z77B](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012TIUTG)
Since they're Pyramid brand, American bike stores probably can order them too.